# How to write a script file in Hive?

Tags: hive

I am a newbie to Hive and trying to write a script file which contains 3 queries in it.I have already created the table in /user/hive/warehouse(default database).I am not sure where to save the script file and what command to use to execute it?Looking forward for a solution.
Info:I am working on hive-ubuntu.
Thanks
Sweesha

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted doesn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in local FS :**

/home/username/some/path/Query1.q (.hql)     -- inside it query is "show databases;"

(give all three Queries in one file if needed)

**from shell $:**

```
user@hostname $ $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -f /home/username/some/path/Query1.q
OK
database_name
db
default
financials
mydb
```

**from hive CLi :**

hive> source /home/username/some/path/Query1.q

Comment: :Thank you for your response.I was able to execute the script from the hive CLi,but,not from the shell.I am getting the following error:

Comment: make sure that each of your Query in script must end with a semi colon, still problem means.paste the err here

Comment: hs1.q:select count(*) from patents;cannot find table patents--error

Comment: dude try this. select count(*) from db_name.patents;

Comment: 'select count(*) from db_name.patents' is working.But when I tried:use default;select count(*) from patents;its not working---wonderering why???.And how to send the result of this script to a file?

Comment: use this line and check when 'use db_name;'is being reflected or not like hive(db_name).'set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;'

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340482/write-the-output-of-a-script-to-a-file-in-hive/21351328#21351328 answer to write result to a file by adding the line on top of ur select query: INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY './outputLocalDir'